# How to align fields in bootstrap columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align the second field of the first column, with the first fields of the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns, as shown in the image below, and have it be responsive using Bootstrap?

[image: shot]

```css
.label1 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label2 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label3 {
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label4 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label5 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label6 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label7 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" id="period">
  <div class="panel-body">

    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">sss</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcode" size="9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcName" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>




            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label2">vvvv</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcode" size="9">

                <label class="label3">bbbb</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="btnClear">
  <option value="volvo">nnnn</option>
  <option value="saab">nnnn</option>
  <option value="opel">nnnnn</option>
  <option value="audi">nnnnn</option>
  </select>
              </div>
            </div>




            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label4">hhhhhh</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35">
              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label5">jjjjj</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35">
              </div>
            </div>




            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label6"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35">
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>


          <div class="col-md-3">


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">kkkkkkk</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">llllll</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">rrrrrra</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">ttttt</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-2">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label7">uuuuu</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcode" maxlength="20" size="7">
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>


    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your first `.form-group` row outside of your first column:

```css
.label1 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label2 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label3 {
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label4 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label5 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label6 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.label7 {
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel panel-default" id="period">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- THIS PIECE MOVED -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="label1">sss</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcode" size="9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcName" size="20">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!---------------------->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label2">vvvv</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcode" size="9">
                <label class="label3">bbbb</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="btnClear">
                  <option value="volvo">nnnn</option>
                  <option value="saab">nnnn</option>
                  <option value="opel">nnnnn</option>
                  <option value="audi">nnnnn</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label4">hhhhhh</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label5">jjjjj</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label6"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">kkkkkkk</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">llllll</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">rrrrrra</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">ttttt</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label1">3</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="20">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label7">uuuuu</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pcode" maxlength="20" size="7">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show me also the changes in order to be responsive

Comment: Responsive how? Technically it's already responsive. What are you expecting?